# SQL: Efficient way to count and group results by like value

Tags: sql, csv, group-by, presto

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+
| id | col2  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  2 | b     |
|  3 | ,b    |
|  4 | c     |
|  5 | d,a   |
|  6 | e,a,b |
+----+-------+
```

What is the most efficient way to query it and return the following ?

```
+------+----------+
| col1 | count_id |
+------+----------+
| a    |        3 |
| b    |        3 |
| c    |        1 |
| d    |        1 |
| e    |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

I was thinking to use `case when` statements but it seems messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Presto you can split the delimited list into an array, then unnest the array. This gives you one record per element in each list. The rest is just aggregation:

```
select s.colx, count(*) cnt 
from mytable t
cross join unnest(split(t.col2, ',')) as s(colx)
group by s.colx
```

If you want the count of *distinct* `id`s (in case there are duplicates within the delimited lists):

```
select s.colx, count(distinct t.id) cnt 
from mytable t
cross join unnest(split(t.col2, ',')) as s(colx)
group by s.colx
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you might need a character table containing all characters which might appear in the second column.  Assuming you did have that, you could try a join approach:

```
WITH letters AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS col1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'z'
)

SELECT
    t1.col1,
    COUNT(t2.col2) AS count_id
FROM letters t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON ',' || t2.col2 || ',' LIKE '%,' || t1.col1 || ',%'
GROUP BY
    t1.col1
ORDER BY
   t1.col1;
```

Note that the accepted answer only works if `col2` happens to have all letters which we want to report. If not, then it would be missing information in the output.